# Access controlling for specific NFT holders via a smart contract address

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, access-control, ethers.js

Is there a way to control accessibility of NFT holders with a smart contract? I want to create a racing game where specific NFT holders can participate. But, I don’t want to list all the NFTs, but rather I want to list a smart contract addresses to make it simpler. My idea is that NFT holders that associated to the smart contract have its access.

- Is there a way to control accessibility of NFTs via smart contract?
- Should I refer to ethers.js and relevant APIs for this kind of logic?

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the questjon, bu you can check if someone has an NFT by calling the balanceOf(address) function on an ERC721 contract. If the wallet has an NFT, then it will return a value greater than 0.

Comment: I have come to make use of Moralis API where I can query NFTs by contract address. https://docs.moralis.io/reference/getcontractnfts I wonder if I can do the same with a smart cotract alone.

Comment: Yes, in an ERC721 contract, with JS and ethers you can do something like `(await (new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, ['balanceOf(address) returns(uint256)'])).balanceOf(WALLET_ADDRESS)) > 0`